# How to properly init RestKit's objectStore to use directory other than Documents

Tags: objective-c, ios, rest, core-data, restkit

So I see there is an init method in RestKit's reference: [objectStoreWithStoreFilename:inDirectory:usingSeedDatabaseName:managedObjectModel:delegate](http://restkit.org/api/master/Classes/RKManagedObjectStore.html#//api/name/objectStoreWithStoreFilename%3ainDirectory%3ausingSeedDatabaseName%3amanagedObjectModel%3adelegate%3a) which suppose to initialize objectStore in specified Directory. "inDirectory" parameter accepts NSString. I've tried @"Library/Caches" and  [self.applicationCachesDirectory absoluteURL] where self.applicationCachesDirectory returns URL of the Caches directory but I'm getting exceptions.

Please tell me how can I specify "Library/Caches" in this method in order to save sqlite DB in the Caches directory instead of Documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working. I've created helper method to get Caches folder path as NSString

```
    - (NSString *)applicationCachesDirectoryString
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    BOOL isDir = NO;
    NSError *error;
    if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cachePath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir == NO) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cachePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    }
    return cachePath;
}
```

and then passed it to the objectStore init method:

```
self.objectManager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:databaseName inDirectory:[self applicationCachesDirectoryString] usingSeedDatabaseName:seedDatabaseName managedObjectModel:managedObjectModel delegate:self];
```